# can someone help me how grouping works in regex in my case if group1 success then group2 should be applicable

Tags: html, regex

[image]

As I have added image for my problem it selecting the end tag though the first condition is not true. It should only select when the first condition is true.

[link](https://regex101.com/r/VcAS6l/3)

```
(<a\s\b(href|title)\b.*\">)?|(<[\/]a>)
```

for the below use cases

1. `<a href=\"http://www.ags.ny.gov/\">www.ags.ny.gov</a>`
2. `<a title=\"ba.com/redeem\" href=\"http://ba.com/rertem\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nkiops noreferrer\">ba.com/rertem</a>.`
3. `<a href=\"http://www.dfs.ny.gov/\">www.ags.ay.gov</a>, for free information`

Comment: not sure anchor tags not showing properly in question 1. <a href=\"dfs.ny.gov\">www.dfs.ny.gov</a> 2. <a title=\"aa.com/redeem\" href=\"aa.com/redeem\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">aa.com/redeem</a> 3. <a href=\"dfs.ny.gov\">www.dfs.ny.gov</a>

Comment: Fixed up formatting for you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Comment: Im not parsing any HTMl code. I need to check regex in string then replace with empty string

Comment: How is that not parsing HTML?

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't understand the question. The language is unclear to me. Can you restate the question? It would help if, too, if you would include example  matches.

Comment: Well we need to verify in string that contains html code. The other end user wants delete the anchor tags completely

Comment: @JaiJeffryes example: Regex expression should select only when starts with <a href|title =\”select code \”>dont select code <\a> reference link https://regex101.com/r/VcAS6l/1 The problem is it is selecting the regex anchor tag at the end  which is not true in the first condition

Comment: Since the end anchor tag is always `</a>`, why bother to select it at all and not just assume that it is there if you aren't grabbing the text in the middle anyway?

Comment: @JaiJeffryes please see my attached image, let me know if you didn't get my concern I can help you out.

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/VcAS6l/4

Comment: @Toto ThankYou for the response it should only work when then anchor tag starts with href or title. like below <a href=\\\"http://www.dfs.ny.gov/\\\">www.dfs.ny.gov</a>, for free information on comparative credit card rates, fees and grace periods.&nbsp;</span>";

<a title = \\\"http://www.blah/\\\">http://www.blah</a>

Comment: In simple words for the below one if group 1 is true then group 2 should applicable 
(<a\s\b(href|title)\b.*\">)?|(<[\/]a>)

Comment: [reviewed version](https://regex101.com/r/VcAS6l/5)

Comment: @Toto it is removing end tag </a> though the tag not started with  (<a\s\b(href|title)\b.*\">). 

example:<a id=\"OLE_LINK2\" class=\"bookmark\" title=\"OLE_LINK2\" name=\"OLE_LINK2\"></a>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including the picture. That helped me understand what you're driving at.

The bad boy is the pipe (logical OR) operator, 10th character from the end of your Regular Expression. That says, "Even if there is no match for the first part, if I have that closing anchor tag, then it's a match."

That's what you said you don't want, but the "|" operator says give you a match for `</a>` no matter what happens before.

I think this is the answer you're looking for. Clarity in your question helps people who want to answer. Your original ask was kind of hazy, but then you added clarification, so I upvoted your question. I hope this answer helps you and encourages you to solicit feedback.

Follow up to your comment:

> I knew the logical operator | giving a match at the end  though
>   the first group is not match. However I need to know how can I update
>   my regex for the second condition should only applicable when the
>   first condition is true.

Okay, let's think about this a little differently. Your requirement is for the truth values at both ends to be TRUE. That's the same as simply saying the whole thing needs to be one long match. The logical operator `|` signifies logical **disjunction**, but your requirement is **conjunction**. Don't split them up at all. Just make one match expression for the whole string you want.

Where you have `|`, code instead `.+`. When I tried that, at first it didn't work because of the `?` quantifier, signifying optionality. In that case, my match picked every character even if the first part wasn't there! Well, don't make the first part optional. Get rid of the `?`.

My environment will look a little different from yours because I work in R, and it changes the escaping a little bit. You'll get the idea, though. My demonstration did what you appear to be describing you want.

```
library(stringr)
str1 <- '<a href=\\\"http"://www.dfs.ny.gov/\\\">www.dfs.ny.gov</a>, for free'
str2 <- '<a title = \\\"http"://www.blah/\\\">www.blah</a>'
str3 <- '<a ID=stuff></a>, for free'

re <- '(<a\\s\\b(href|title)\\b.*\">).+(<[/]a>)'
str_extract(str1, re)
str_extract(str2, re)
str_extract(str3, re)
```

My results for matching those three strings in my demo were as follows. My change to your RegEx matched the first two and did not match the third (indicated by NA in my output, which means Not Available, as in no match), which are your expected results.

```
> str_extract(str1, re)
[1] "<a href=\\\"http\"://www.dfs.ny.gov/\\\">www.dfs.ny.gov</a>"
> str_extract(str2, re)
[1] "<a title = \\\"http\"://www.blah/\\\">www.blah</a>"
> str_extract(str3, re)
[1] NA
```

Comment: I knew the logical operator | giving a match at the end </a> though the first group is not match. However I need to know how can I update my regex for the second condition should only applicable when the first condition is true.

Comment: Thank You for the response below is the link, sorry to say it is selecting completely including value of the anchor tag which shouldn't happen 

https://regex101.com/r/4RW5MZ/1

Comment: @Nick. But you didn't try my advice. You left the quantifier for optional, `?', in. That's a deal breaker. That's precisely why it doesn't work. My code runs. This is mine: (<a\\s\\b(href|title)\\b.*\">).+(<[/]a>). This is yours: <a\s\b(href|title)\b.*?\">.+<[\/]a>. If you do what I did, you'll get the same results as me.

Comment: @Nick. My RegEx101 sample works. I showed you how to fix your code. https://regex101.com/r/QNHr3Q/1

Comment: Thankyou, Really Appreciated

Comment: Hey, @Nick. I'm delighted we got to what works for you. It would be a kindness on your part to mark my answer as the accepted one.